# Laravel 5.7 dynamic rate limit not working

Tags: laravel-5.7, rate-limiting

In my api routes I have the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:rate_limit,1', 'prefix' => 'recruiter/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\Recruiter\V1'], function ()
{

    Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index');
 });
```

The `rate_limit` parameter is a field in my users table and is set to 100 but after 60 hits per minute i seem to reach the limit.

In kernal.php I have:

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
],
```

now the docs doesn't mention anything about needing to comment the above out when using dynamic rate limit?

I thought the whole idea of dynamic rate limit was being able to set your own limit but clearly not - whatever is defined in kernal.php overides any other value unless it below the value define in kernal.php.

Answer (score 1):

You are throttling twice.  Once in the group you created, and once in the api.

If you look in the main RouteServiceProvider you will see that the api file is surrounded with the api milddleware you set in the Kernel.

It throttles ALL the routes inside the api.php file.

To avoid this remove the throttle from the api in Kernel, move your routes out of the api.php and make another routes file or you could change the service provider to reflect your changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Http/Kernel.php` setup MAX of `throttle` for `rate_limit`.

Comment: for "rate limit 20 queries per second" set 1200